# Xcode Git Merge project.pbxproj file

Tags: ios, xcode, git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have 264 conflicts in my project.pbxproj file when I'm merging two local branches in Xcode. I tried my best to merge them but for some conflicts I cannot even see the drop down button to select left or right because there are just too many different parts. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use their version of the xcodeproj, then manually add everything you need back.

Comment: The best piece of advice, actually

Answer (score 1):

Do not attempt to resolve the conflicts in this multicolumn display (which is basically Apple's own FileMerge application). It just can't handle this big a situation.

Instead, since a file with merge errors is just a normal text file with a bunch of very obvious markup showing what the problems are, open the file as text and resolve those errors manually in a text editor (such as BBEdit).

Comment: But see https://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/09/automatically-resolving-git-merge-conflicts-in-xcodes-project-pbxproj/ for another suggestion.